# Soundcloud's HTML5 Widget & OAuth Token?

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to figure out how to use the widget.load method along while passing in a SoundCloud OAuth token.

Neither this:

```
 // load SC widget
        widget.load("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + $scope.soundCloudTrackID + "?oauth_token=" + $scope.scToken, {
            show_artwork: false,
            auto_play: true,
            show_comments: false,
            buying: false,
            liking: false,
            sharing: false,
            show_playcount: false,
            show_user: false,
        });
```

Or this:

```
 // load SC widget
        widget.load("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + $scope.soundCloudTrackID {
            show_artwork: false,
            auto_play: true,
            show_comments: false,
            buying: false,
            liking: false,
            sharing: false,
            show_playcount: false,
            show_user: false,
            oauth_token: '323232'
        });
```

Seem to be working for me - the oauth_token parameter keeps getting stripped from the URL.  Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - it looks like the API call returns a "SecretURL" that you can use to play the track.  All is well now!